# $U,W$ are subspaces. show $\dim(U+W) = 1+\dim(U \cap W)$, then $\{U+W,U\cap W\}=\{U,W\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

This is a question from a review package that is causing me some trouble.

Let $U,W$ be subspaces of a finite dimensional vector space. Show if $\dim(U+W) = 1+\dim(U \cap W)$, then $\{U+W,U\cap W\}=\{U,W\}$.

I know that for $\{U+W,U\cap W\}=\{U,W\}$ to be true, one of two cases must happen. Either $U\subseteq W$ or $W\subseteq U$, since $U \cap W$ must equal $U$ or $W$. However we can assume without loss of generality that either one is true.

I'm not sure how to show the implication (maybe through contraposition?). Any hints and help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have
$$
(U\cap W)\subset U\subset (U+W)\quad\text{and}\quad (U\cap W)\subset W\subset (U+W).
$$
Because of the hypothesis on the dimensions, each space $U$ and $W$ must be either $U\cap W$ or $U+W$ (these last two spaces have dimensions differing by $1$ and so there is no room for other integers between the two).

Now note that $U$ and $W$ cannot have the same dimension, because if so, then 
$$
\dim(U+W)=\dim U+\dim W-\dim(U\cap W)=2\dim U-\dim(U\cap W),
$$
but also 
$$
\dim(U+W)=1+\dim(U\cap W).
$$
Indeed, since the two right-hand sides are equal, we get
$$
2\dim U=1+2\dim(U\cap W),
$$
an even number equal to an odd number.